# combine values for same key for array of objects

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have the following input data

```
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": [
      "1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": [
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "value": [
      "3"
    ]
  }
]
```

and would like to merge the values into an array, grouped by the same key. i.e. the following desired output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "value": [
      "3"
    ]
  }
]
```

any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One option can be using `groupBy` and then accommodating the groups you get like this:

```
valuesOf(payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.key)) 
    map ((group, index) -> {
    "key": group[0].key,
    "value": flatten(group.value)
})
```

This is producing the output you shared.

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach. a bit different usage of functions.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ($."key") mapObject {
    "key": $[0].key,
    "value": $ map {
        temp: $.value[0]
    }.temp
}
```